# Defining dynamic function parameters in Typescript

Tags: typescript

Given this:

```js
type params = Parameters<(x: string, y:number)=>void>
```

In the pseudo code below how does one make `fn` to be `(x: string, y:number)=>void`, but using the `params` type?

```js
type fn = (...params)=>void // type should be (x: string, y:number)=>void
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
type fn = (...p: params)=>void
```

should work. Type the rest parameter with type `params`.

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=3&ssc=31&pln=3&pc=1#code/C4TwDgpgBGCGBOsC2BnKBeKAFByLAnhQB4AKADwC4oVh4BLAOwHMAaKESxgVyQCNCASnQA+AG4B7egBMRAWABQi0JCgAzRhiikAdHrDU4iVMPFTpQA)